# Unable to find image locally

Tags: docker

I have a docker image:

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
elucidbio/capcompute   local               a5ed348be9f8        About a minute ago   2.27GB
```

But when I try and start it, it fails:

```
$docker run --name capcompute elucidbio/capcompute
Unable to find image 'elucidbio/capcompute:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: repository elucidbio/capcompute not found: does not exist or no pull access.
```

What stupid thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 16):

Your tags dont match. Your local image tag is "local" but its looking for "latest" because you didn't specify a tag. To run it you should append the tag of "local".

```
docker run --name capcompute elucidbio/capcompute:local
```